# Should the Update Manager module be uninstalled when installing with Composer?

Tags: 8, updating

Drupal 8 is installed with Composer and I use it to update. So I uninstalled the Update Manager module provided by the core.

Now when I go to /admin/reports/status, I have the following warning.

> [image]

Should the Update Manager module be uninstalled when Drupal is installed with Composer?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have Update Manager installed on all my live sites.

While I use composer to manage all of my sites, I am do not blindly `composer update` and push out.  I like to read changelogs and make sure I regression test thoroughly.

So, I have email notifications for updates turned on for all of my sites.  Most are set for daily notification for all updates, but a handful of internal-only sites (as in behind the firewall) set for security updates only.

Then I can test and plan what updates go out when during my maintenance windows.  Or for security updates, triage how critical they are to go out outside the normal windows.

Comment: Thank you, I monitor the update with RSS feed modules installed on my site and Thunderbird. If I reinstall the Update module, it does not work anymore https://imgur.com/a/oa9dkkA